# jq append data and keep the rest

Tags: jq

I'm trying to add a value to array with jq and keep the rest of the content:

```
   "access":{
      "allowed_users":[
         "admin",
         "test",
      ],
```

The above is what I want to append. If I use `jq '.access.allowed_users + [ "test2" ]'` it will add a new entry there but the rest of the file is lost so I can't recreate the configuration file again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you mean you want to append *to* the JSON that you show and that the JSON document is well-formed,

```bash
$ cat file.json
{
  "access": {
    "allowed_users": [
      "admin",
      "test"
    ]
  }
}
```

you can do

```bash
$ jq '.access.allowed_users += ["test32"]' file.json
{
  "access": {
    "allowed_users": [
      "admin",
      "test",
      "test32"
    ]
  }
}
```

It uses the `+=` to add to the array by assigning a new element to it.

With a new value in a shell variable:

```bash
$ data='My "awesome" data'
$ jq --arg value "$data" '.access.allowed_users += [$value]' file.json
{
  "access": {
    "allowed_users": [
      "admin",
      "test",
      "My \"awesome\" data"
    ]
  }
}
```

To add many entries in one go, it's easiest to add them with `--args`:

```bash
$ jq '.access.allowed_users += $ARGS.positional' file.json --args Bilbo Frodo Sam Merry Pippin
{
  "access": {
    "allowed_users": [
      "admin",
      "test",
      "Bilbo",
      "Frodo",
      "Sam",
      "Merry",
      "Pippin"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that `--args` and the subsequent arguments to that option must be the last thing on the command line.

To make these changes to your file, use a temporary file:

```bash
jq ...one-of-the-above-approaches... >tmp.json &&
mv tmp.json file.json
```

The `&&` prevents the original file from being overwritten if `jq` for some reason fails.

Comment: How to prevent escape characters being written when using a shell variable?

Comment: @burntsugar I don't understand what you mean.